# Apache's VirtualHosts wildcard in ServerName attribute

Tags: apache, wildcard, virtualhost

Is it possible to create a "wildcard" on  ServerName attribute on a VirtualHost statement?

I currently have something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName testhost
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/testhost/"
</VirtualHost>
```

What I would like to is something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName $serverRequest
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/" + $serverRequest
</VirtualHost>
```

So I could redirect all similar hosts to a same-name directory. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you're after [Dynamically Configured Mass Virtual Hosting](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/mass.html).